# Using a viewmodel and passing a query to the same view

Tags: c#, razor

I am new to mvc architecture. I want to create a view with a form to store data to db and a division to show the details using a query.This view is using a viewmodel- Add_session_ViewModel.

The issue is that if I am including the viewmodel to view there is an error in display section and if I am including the list there is a error in form.
The codes are as follows:

CONTROLLER:

```
public ActionResult Add_session()
    {





        //display data


        var query =( from a in db.Session_details_feedback
                    join b in db.Employee_Details_Feedback on a.Trainer_id equals b.Emp_id
                    select new
                    {

                        a.Session_date,
                        a.Session_name,
                        b.Emp_name
                    } ).ToList();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
          List<Add_session_ViewModel> sessionList = new List<Add_session_ViewModel>
            {
              new Add_session_ViewModel { Session_name=item.Session_name,Session_date=item.Session_date,emp_name=item.Emp_name}


          };
            ViewData.Model = sessionList;



        return View(ViewData.Model);
    }
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
public class Add_session_ViewModel : DbContext

{
    public string Session_name { get; set; }
    public int Trainer_id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Session_date { get; set; }
     public string emp_name { get; set; }
    public IList<Add_session_ViewModel> Session_List { get; set; }


}
```

VIEW:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add_session", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
            {

                <div class="form-group">


                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Session_name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = " Enter Session name" })


                </div>
                <div class="form-group">


                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Session_date, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = " Enter Session date" })


                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Trainer_id, ViewBag.TrainerList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select Trainer")

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="add" type="submit" value="ADD" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>

</center>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Session</th>
                <th>Trainer</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Session_date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Session_name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emp_name)
                </td>

            </tr>

        }
    </table>
```

I have  been looking for a solution for days, still didnt get any.
It would be appreciative if anyone can give me a solution.

Thank you.

my viewmodel is :

```
public class Add_session_ViewModel 

{
    public string Session_name { get; set; }
    public int Trainer_id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Session_date { get; set; }
     public string emp_name { get; set; }
}

the view use all these properties  through a form.

At the same time I need to get the data using the below query and get it displayed on the same view:

 var query =( from a in db.Session_details_feedback
                        join b in db.Employee_Details_Feedback on a.Trainer_id equals b.Emp_id
                        select new
                        {

                            a.Session_date,
                            a.Session_name,
                            b.Emp_name
                        } ).ToList();
```

I have no ides how to bind the query and viewmodel to the view at the same time

Comment: which error did you get?

Comment: What kind of exception occurred? Is that exception thrown inside `DisplayFor` part in `foreach` loop?

Comment: BTW Why do you inherit the ViewModel from DbContext? Never seen that before

Comment: I miss the @Model=... line in the View. Is that a copy/paste error or is it not there?

Comment: Error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Add_session_ViewModel' because 'Add_session_ViewModel' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator

Comment: when I include @model FeedBack_Form.Models.Add_session_ViewModel there is no error in form.

Comment: Well, then include it - Question solved

Comment: So in your view do you have `@model FeedBack_Form.Models.Add_session_ViewModel`?

Comment: @model IEnumerable<FeedBack_Form.Models.Add_session_ViewModel> on using this there are no errors in displaying section.  And at the same we cant use both the codes ,right?

Comment: you are doing some bad stuff in your `Add_session` get method. instead why you not map your linq query result to directly viewmodel?

Comment: ok let me provide you the right way to bind your view model to view

Comment: @JijithJeevan, come into chat from below link in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

Remove the `DbContext` as base class to your view model,

```
public class Add_session_ViewModel
{
    public string Session_name { get; set; }
    public int Trainer_id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Session_date { get; set; }
    public string emp_name { get; set; }
    public IList<Add_session_ViewModel> Session_List { get; set; }
}
```

Then try to map your LINQ query result to directly list of your view model.

```
public ActionResult Add_session()
{
    Add_session_ViewModel model = new Add_session_ViewModel(); 

    var result =(from a in db.Session_details_feedback
                join b in db.Employee_Details_Feedback on a.Trainer_id equals b.Emp_id
                select new Add_session_ViewModel   //<= Note here
                {
                     Session_date = a.Session_date,
                     Session_name = a.Session_name,
                     emp_name = b.Emp_name
                }).ToList(); 

    model.Session_List = result;      

    return View(model);    //<= Return model to view instead of "ViewData"
}
```

And then your view must have a view model of

```
@model FeedBack_Form.Models.Add_session_ViewModel
```

And change your `foreach` loop to

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Session_List)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188596/discussion-on-answer-by-er-sho-using-a-viewmodel-and-passing-a-query-to-the-same). If the answer does not solve your problem, then update the question and improve your [mcve].